# NSUserDefaults - displaying a UIAlertView on first launch - button behaviour

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, uialertview

I am using NSUserDefaults to display a UIAlertView the first time my application is loaded.  The Alert has a Dismiss and a Rate Now button.  The Dismiss is self explanatory and works fine, however, I want the Rate Now button to open up the relevant location within the App Store on the device.  I am using the following code in my AppDelegate.m file.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *alertshown = [defaults stringForKey:@"alertshown"]; {
if (alertshown == nil) {

    UIAlertView *oneTimeWelcome = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle: @"Thank You"
                                  message: @"Blah Blah Blah Blah"
                                  delegate: self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                  otherButtonTitles:@"Rate Now",nil];
    [oneTimeWelcome show];
    [oneTimeWelcome release];

    [defaults setObject:@"alertwasdisplayed" forKey:@"alertshown"];
}
```

On a previous use of a second button in a UIAlertView I have used this code to call a new view;

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        // Do something wonderful here
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        AppSupportView *controller = [[AppSupportView alloc] initWithNibName:@"AppSupportView" bundle:nil];
        controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
        [controller release];

    }
```

However, this does not work when the code is used in the AppDelegate.m file??  Any examples would be great to get my Rate Now button to open up App Store.  Sorry about the formatting but it wouldnt let me alter the text

EDIT - This is the entirety of the code I am dealing with in the AppDelegate.m file

{ //This following block of code displays a UIAlert when the user first opens the application. This is only displays if alertshown == 0

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *alertshown = [defaults stringForKey:@"alertshown"]; {
if (alertshown == nil) {

    UIAlertView *oneTimeWelcome = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle: @"Thank You"
                                  message: @"Thanks, please rate blah blah blah"
                                  delegate: self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                  otherButtonTitles:@"Rate Now",nil];
    [oneTimeWelcome show];
    [oneTimeWelcome release];

    [defaults setObject:@"alertwasdisplayed" forKey:@"alertshown"];
```

}
    }

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        // Yes, do something
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
```

Comment: I hope you know what happens with apps that ask for a rating at first launch. Hint: If people download your app they want to use it, they don't want to leave your app immediately to write a review.

Comment: @Fluchtpunkt _ yes, I agree. And subsequent thought has led me to remove this from the first launch alert.  However, it is still an issue which I need to resolve even if just for the sake of learning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume when you say it doesn't work, that it doesn't compile.

You are calling

```
 [self presentModalViewController]
```

from the app delegate, which is not a UIViewController.  You need to instantiate a UIViewController and call it from within there.  It's good practice to get out of the appdelegate as soon as you can anyway - just do APP level things there, and put UI, processing, etc code into view controllers.

Comment: @Mike - Hi Mike, Im actually not calling [self presentModalViewController] - I just used that as an example of how i previously used this.  It seems to have a problem with this line - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

Comment: Ok, please be more specific about "does not work" - crash, compile error, blank screen, gremlin attack...

Comment: No Gremlin Attacks unfortunately.  It produces a semantic issue on the -(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex { saying use of undeclared identifier 'alertView'

Comment: I'd rather have a syntax error than a gremlin attack, but I digress.  Try changing "alertView" - the variable name to "foo" and see if that's it or if it thinks the method declaration is part of another method.

Comment: It now says 'use of undeclared identifier foo, did you mean for?' The exact same code works flawlessly in my main ViewController.m file.  Is it a that because it is in the AppDelegate.m it just can't be done?

Comment: No, I meant "foo".  It seems to think that you are not starting a new method declaration, but rather continuing the previous method.  Can you post the code from that area?

Comment: Are you missing a close } somewhere above this line?

Comment: Yeah i know you meant 'foo' - But xCode actually said in it's warning 'Did you mean for'.  I could post the code, wouldnt format very well in this little box, ill edit the Q with it.

Comment: Indeed I did Mike, *oops* - Must have been those Gremlins! Thank you, it is working now. You are a gentleman and a scholar.

Comment: Glad you got it working.  XCode 4 has a preference setting that automatically creates a closing } when you open one.  Get in the habit of always using curlies; moreover, open it, close it, then fill in the middle.  Soon you won't have to think about it, nor debug issus like this one.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your AppDelegate adheres to the `UIAlertViewDelegate`-protocol.

Example definition from an AppDelegate header file:

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, my AppDelegate.h looks like this - @interface Total_HealthAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate> { so i think its fine from that point

Comment: @iPhoneHelpr - ok then, add some logging or breakpoints to your app and check if the part in question (alertview-delegate method) is actually invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Set Some default values for `NSUserDefault` value -> if it is **NULL** then show `AlertView` and fill some value to `NSUserdefault`. Or else nothing.